# Navigation Link in a context menu not working

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I have a navigation link as an option in a context menu but it does nothing.

```swift
.contextMenu{
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello")){
        Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
   }
 }
```

I am not sure why and I couldn't find anything relating to this issue. Is this something that can work or do I need to implement it in another way?

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationLink` should be right in `NavigationView`, but contextMenu is out of context of `NavigationView`, because it is in own view hierarchy.

A possible solution is to activate link by button from context menu, like

```
@State private var showEdit = false

// ...

.background(
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello"), isActive: $showEdit){
       EmptyView()
   }
)
.contextMenu {
    Button(action: { self.showEdit = true }) {
        Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi I have implemented the code the way you have but I have a slight issue. This implementation uses the background modifier opens the Text view on a tap of the view I add the .background to and when I press the label in the context menu however I was going to use that tap gesture to open a different view. Is there another way to fix my problem?